# Cleaning urls my htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have looked for answers but none have worked for me. I want to clean up my urls removing the page name, extension and variables on all my pages in all folders.
so

http://www.example.co.uk/home/index.php?username=ben&id=1

to

http://www.example.co.uk/home/

and

http://www.example.co.uk/profile/index.php?blog=test&id=45

to

http://www.example.co.uk/profile/

ect....

im running apache

thanks

sorry for late reply. so far i have

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+\.)?example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

To force the www. and also remove the file name and extension

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far.

Comment: have edited above to show what i have

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable mod rewrite module in your apache configuration.
In your .htaccess file try some basic rewrite rule.

If you rewrite 
http://www.example.co.uk/home/index.php?username=ben&id=1
to
http://www.example.co.uk/home/
you are losing the parameters "username=ben&id=1".

Some rewrite tutorials from google sesarch
https://www.google.com/search?q=mod+rewrite+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb

http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/